# Play Framework with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, scala, playframework, spring-security

I'm new to the Play framework and want to implement some authentication for my webapp.

I have already some experiences with Spring and Spring Security and want to use this, but I'm not sure if this makes sense, because the Spring Security is mainly for the ServletAPI.

Does it makes sense to integrate Play with Spring Security?

Thanks.

After further searches I have found this post:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/K7l6vHa0UUA/MYDlsaIfJEMJ

It seems to be possible, but still a lot of Play specific implementations (filter, etc.) have to be done.

Comment: Just curious, what did you end up doing? I am looking into the same problem - looking for an robust, production proven authentication model and came across Spring Security and I was wondering if it can be used with the PlayFramework.

Comment: I used finally the Pac4j library for Play: https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j it is a very straight-forward implemenation and worked very good for me. Also the community is very active and supportive.

Answer (score 0):

You should - perhaps - look on [Deadbolt 2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2). It is dedicated solution, so it will run out of the box.

Comment: The Deadbolt2 provides only authorization part, you'll still have to implemnt or find ready solution for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense to use spring security with play. Spring security has been used in lots of projects, and writing secure code is much harder than it looks.

You have two problems. One is authentication. You need to do something to achieve authentication. This means either twiddling play so it becomes a stateful container (but then again, why would you use play at all in this case?) or throwing spring-security-web and deadbolt very hard at each other so you use spring for authentication, but integrate with the cookie goodness of play so you don't have to store stuff in a session object on the server side. I would suggest you fetch the authorities that drive authorization from somewhere for every request, though. You want to keep the session size down.

The Security object also has some good hints on how to go about doing this.

Authorization in spring is not hard to handle as long as you have got an authentication object stored in a threadlocal or something. Create something that calls the spring access decision voters in a wrapper - something like

```
def handleRequest ... {
  withAuthorization(<list of roles necessary>) {
    service code
  }
}
```

should do the trick. For added goodness, add a flag in a threadlocal when you do this - the presence of the flag makes it easy to write assertions in your tests that require authorization to have taken place. This is one of the biggest security issues for developers out there - see https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/862.html

Hope this helps.